# The Rosenbrock function is positive definite for all $x$ with $f(x) < 0.0025$

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = 100(x_2-x_1^2)^2 + (1-x_1)^2$ be the Rosenbrock function.
>
> Show that the Hessian of the Rosenbrock function is positive definite for all $x$ with $f(x) < 0.0025$

I thought I should use Sylverster's criterion here, so I calculated the Hessian of $f$:

$\nabla^2 f(x) = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1200x_1^2-400x_2+2 \quad& 400 \cdot x_1 \\
-400x_1 & 200\\
\end{pmatrix}$

and the determinants:

1. $det(\nabla^2 f(x)_1) = 1200x_1^2-400x_2+2$
2. $det(\nabla^2 f(x)_2) = 240000x_1^2-8000x_2+400+1600x_1^2$.

But I do not know how to proceed from here.

Could you help me?

Comment: Use [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) now

Comment: You may use the $(2,2)$-th entry instead of the $(1,1)$-th entry of the Hessian matrix. The $(2,2)$-th entry here is clearly positive. So, it remains to prove that the determinant of the Hessian is positive when $f(x)<0.0025$. Note that the determinant is $400\left[200(x_1^2-x_2)+1\right]$ while $f(x)\ge100(x_1^2-x_2)^2$. The rest should be easy.

Comment: The minimum is at $x_1=x_2=1$ Calculating the hessian at this point following with the eigenvalues we found $\lambda_1 = 1001.6, \lambda_2 = 0.39936$ characterizing this point as a minimum, being well approximated with a positive definite quadratic.